# Inserting values into multiindexed dataframe with sline(None)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to insert entries on each first level but it fails:

```
import string
alph = string.ascii_lowercase

n=5
inds = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(i,j) for i in alph[:n] for j in range(1,n)])
t = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(0,10, len(inds)), index=inds).sort_index()

# inserting value np.nan on every alphabetical level at index 0 on the second level
t.loc[(slice(None), 0), :]=np.nan
```

KeyError: 0

Expected output:

[image]

How can I do these `np.nan` insertions on the second level as shown on the picture?

This code piece works, indicating that something is wrong with the `slice(None)`:

```
t.loc[('a', 0), :]=np.nan
t = t.sort_index()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do by [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with new index formed by [`union`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.union.html) with the needed insertions.

```
t.reindex(t.index.union(list(zip(alph[:n], [0]*n))))
```

Output (the values will be different because data is random):

```
       0
a 0  NaN
  1  0.0
  2  3.0
  3  5.0
  4  5.0
b 0  NaN
  1  0.0
  2  7.0
  3  6.0
  4  2.0
c 0  NaN
  1  5.0
  2  9.0
  3  8.0
  4  2.0
d 0  NaN
  1  8.0
  2  9.0
  3  4.0
  4  8.0
e 0  NaN
  1  5.0
  2  4.0
  3  6.0
  4  1.0
```

Comment: But why doesn't `loc` work with `slice(None)` and works without `slice(None)` when one uses a specific value for the zeros level?

Comment: `t.loc[('a', 0), :]=np.nan;  t = t.sort_index()` works.

Comment: You are right, but then you need to do for every value. As per https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/advanced.html#advanced-reindexing-and-alignment you could use reindex to broadcast values or *set Places NA/NaN in locations having no value in the previous index* as per "reindex" doc.